# fadeln script not working well

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I have a problem with my script. What I do is take the css id of any tag `<p>` and tell him in the script: after x remove the tag `<a>`. It is working well for the category Y but in category X it is not working, and I'm not getting any error.

My code:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  var i = '';
  for (i = '9'; i <= '22'; i++) {
    $('div > p.lessonsrow-' + i).find('a[href]').attr('href', '#lock');
    $('div > p.lessonsrow-' + i).find('i.cercale2').replaceWith('<i class="cercale2 fa fa-lock fa-1x"></i>')
  }
});
```

the tags HTML:

```
foreach ($lessonsid as $row) {
  $html .= $counter % 2 == 0 ? '
    <div class="span12 bar_lessons">
      <p class="lessonsrow-' . $row->id . '">
        <i class="cercale2 glyphicon glyphicon-play fa-1x"></i>
        <a href="' . url() . '/gui/' . $url . '/' . Request::segment(3) . '/lessons/' . $row->courses_id . '/vod/' . $row->id . '">' . trans('lessons.' . $row->name) . '</a>
      </p>
      <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, con</p>
    </div>' : '
    <div class="span12 bar_lessons2">
      <p class="lessonsrow-' . $row->id . '">
        <i class="cercale2 glyphicon glyphicon-play fa-1x"></i>
        <a href="' . url() . '/gui/' . $url . '/' . Request::segment(3) . '/lessons/' . $row->courses_id . '/vod/' . $row->id . '">' . trans('lessons.' . $row->name) . '</a>
      </p>
      <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, con</p>
    </div>';

  $counter++;
}
```

I use laravel fraemwork.

Images:

http://prntscr.com/60ystp - This catagory is working well

http://prntscr.com/60ysna - This catagory is not working

Comment: Please show your actual rendered OUTPUT (HTML). This question has nothing to do with PHP or your server-side code.

Comment: what you mean? 
after is print the code to the html?

Comment: @idan003 The code as rendered in the browser

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery(function($) {
                        var i ='';
                        for(i='9'; i <= '22'; i++) {

                            $('div > p.lessonsrow-'+i).find('a[href]').attr('href','#lock');
                            $('div > p.lessonsrow-'+i).find('i.cercale2').replaceWith('<i class="cercale2 fa fa-lock fa-1x"></i>')
                        }

                    });

                </script>

Comment: who can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to loop a char. This for loop will run 0 times. Try with this javascript. Your loop also wanted to iterate between 9-22. I guess ids are not only between 9-22. So do it for all applicable div>p

```
jQuery(function ($)
{
    $('div.span12 > p').find('a[href]').attr('href', '#lock');
    $('div.span12 > p').find('i.cercale2').replaceWith('<i class="cercale2 fa fa-lock fa-1x"></i>')
});
```

Comment: is not good, after i do the loop i need do take the <p class="lessons-9">
and close it. and again the code works good but  in 1 catagory is not work and the 2 catagory is work. so i do`t know why.

Comment: no is still in 1 catagory working and in the catagory 2 not working.